# C# or other: while loop to update inputs and process?

Tags: c#, input, while-loop

I am developing a monitoring/control software that, basically, reads inputs (via network modules) and generates events after processing them.

While input can depend on communication speed, and can be ran in multi threading, processing is basically a continuous loop, basically:

```
while (true)
{
    readInputs();
    process();
}
```

this seems to be pretty straightforward but, as you can imagine, cpu will be at 100%.
And if you want to have other loops running, mainly for timed events.
So, while processes can have a sleep at the end, the timed events can't.

My question is: what is the best way to have inputs collected and processed, without having the app to eat full cpu cycles?

Update 1:
The application is multithread and has an user interface.
Timers are applied to update the user interface (from the shared memory - processed stuff and input status).
While loops are used for input read and processing.

Comment: How are you reading your inputs? The `Console.ReadXXX` methods don't smash the CPU..

Comment: @SimonWhitehead "reads inputs (via network modules)" --> not Console.

Comment: Silly me. I'm not comprehending English very well tonight unfortunately :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While is not a bad idea here but you have two problems.

1) CPU last 
2) maybe software hanging while reading/writing

to solve the first problem just give some sleep to the current thread.

```
while (true)
{
    readInputs();
    Thread.Sleep(300); // more then 100
    process();
}
```

To solve the second problem by reading and writing with SpinWait.SpinUntil

I hope this will help.
Greetings

Comment: Well ... i think this might be the best option for the adopted model. There is a need for continuous update and process. Adding sleep for all tasks can not be usable when you want tasks to be more accurate.

Answer (score 2):

The best way, in my option, would be to use a timer and call those two functions every second - or more frequently if required, but it depends how much work they do.

For example:

```
System.Timers.Timer timer;

void SetupTimer()
{
    timer= new System.Timers.Timer();//create timer
    timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);//attach event handler
    timer.Interval = 1000;//set to fire every 1 second
    timer.Enabled = true;//starts the timer
}

void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    DoTasks();
}

void DoTasks()
{
    readInputs();
    process();    
}
```

You could also add an `isBusy` flag to ensure that if the tasks are still being processed when the next timer elapsed event occurs then it wont run them again, of course it depends on your exact needs. For example:

```
bool isBusy = false;
void DoTasks()
{
    if(isBusy)
        return;
    isBusy = true;
    readInputs();
    process();    
    isBusy = false;
}
```

Comment: Isn't the timer callback synchronous? i.e. theres no way it will get called again if while still processing.

Comment: @Ibasa: You may be right. I seem to remember something like that, but I am not 100% sure

Comment: @Ibasa: After reading the "Remarks" section [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.elapsed.aspx), it isn't completely clear. I think you can have both ways if you configure it certain ways, but I can't work out which one it is saying is the default. It does also suggest using a flag to avoid race conditions under one of the setups

Comment: The default is that SynchronizingObject is null, and thus the callback does not have to be reentrant. There is also a race condition with Stop but that's probably not important for this question.